# VBA how to check range of cells for value and insert Data Validation list

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I would like the below code to insert a data validation list with a source of "new_DDM3" in the range "B5:B61" where ever the value of the cell is "Choose".

This would happen when the selection in "B2" is changed.

```
 Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
With Range("B5")
    .Formula = "=myformula"
    .Value = .Value
If Range("B5") = "Choose" Then
With .Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=new_DDM3"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True


End With
End If
End With
End If
End Sub
```

Any advise is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run the same code across all the cells in B5:B61, then you can use a loop

```
For Each cell in Range("B5:B61").Cells
    With cell
        .Formula = "=myformula"
        .Value = .Value
    If cell = "Choose" Then
    With .Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=new_DDM3"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True    
    End With
next cell
```

Comment: Jaycal, I attempted to use your code however I get a error "mismatch" at `if cell = "Choose" then`

Comment: My apologies Jaycal, you're code worked excellent! In my haste and excitement I forgot to replace "myformula" with my actual formula.

Comment: Any way if the cell does not say "choose" it can delete any existing validation?

Comment: to do that you can use the `IF-ELSE-ENDIF` structure. Then, in the `ELSE` section, you can do whatever you need to do if the cell is not equal to "Choose"